# java .contains not returning the correct boolean?

Tags: java, contains

Simple issue occurring. Not sure why it's not working? Screenshot attached.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgt9v.png)

Comment: Could you post the code and error you are receiving instead of just a screenshot?

Comment: Beyond not using screen shots. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. I am guessing that your class does not have proper implementations for the equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: If you look at the failing test case, and ask yourself the values of each of the && sides, I think you'll find the test is correct. Fixing it sounds like it's part of your assignment. :-)

Comment: never mind, seems to be an issue on the site's part... (codingbat) sorry everyone

Comment: It is not an error, you just misunderstood the problem (I took sometime to get it too), It asks to return `true` if there is at least one xyz that is not preceeded by a dot (.). In that case, clearly that second one meets this conditions

Comment: oh ok how embarrassing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to take this:

```
public static boolean xyzThere(String s) {
  return !s.contains(".xyz") && s.contains("xyz");
}
```

And break it up.

For starters, it's not enough to say whether the string contains xyz, because (as in the failing test case) there may be many instances of xyz in the string.

So you need to figure out what the logic is.

One way to express it would be to say:

We always fail *unless* there is at least one sequence xyz which is not also an .xyz

So maybe we're looking for a loop.

```
public static boolean xyzThere(String str) {
    boolean result = false;
    String s = str;
    int n = s.indexOf("xyz");
    while(n >= 0) {
        // if n is 0 then there was no preceeding dot so we win
        if (n == 0) { return true; }
        // if the immediately preceedding character was not a '.' return true
        char c = s.charAt(n-1);
        if (c != '.') { return true; }
        // otherwise keep looking until no more instances of "xyz" in the string
        s = s.substring(n + 3);
        n = s.indexOf("xyz");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that if they told you to use .contains for your homework it can be rewritten to use that instead of .indexOf, but it's a little bit harder.